# Как работает java.util.concurrent.Phaser?

Tags: java, concurrency

Как, в данном задании, `Phaser` понимает, что нити являются его участниками?

Вызвав метод `arriveAndAwaitAdvance()`, он присоединяет нить, в которой вызван, к пасеру в состоянии прибыла на барьер?

`Phaser` понимает, что нити являются его участниками, за счет методов `arriveAndAwaitAdvance` и `arrive`?

Без их вызова в данной задаче он будет пустой?

```
package com.javarush.test.level28.lesson10.home01;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
        characters.add(new Plant());
        characters.add(new Plant());
        characters.add(new Zombie());
        characters.add(new Zombie());
        characters.add(new Zombie());
        start(characters);
    }

    private static boolean isEveryoneReady = false;

    private static void start(List<Character> characters) throws InterruptedException {
        final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1 + characters.size());

        for (final Character character : characters) {
            final String member = character.toString();
            System.out.println(member + " присоединился к игре");

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(member + " готовится играть");
                    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                    if (!isEveryoneReady) {
                        isEveryoneReady = true;
                        System.out.println("Игра началась!");
                    }
                    character.run();
                }
            }.start();

        }

        phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
    }
}
```

Comment: фазер один, у него счетчик, ему не нужно понимать или присоединять нить, что вы имели ввиду под этими словами, что значит будет пустой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Phaser` -- это разновидность барьера, аналогичен `CyclicBarrier` и `CountDownLatch`, но отличается более гибкой настройкой.

Барьер в общем виде представляет собой следующее:

- задается количество потоков, которое должно собраться на барьере
- каждый поток, прибывающий на барьер, блокируется
- как только на барьере собирается заданное выше количество потоков, барьер "открывается", и все потоки продолжают свою работу

Подробнее почитать про барьеры (в т.ч. про эти три реализации) и посмотреть иллюстрацию их работы можно [в статье на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277669/).

В приведенном коде `Phaser` работает так:

- инициализируется значением участников `1 + characters.size()`
- дальше потоки в количестве `characters.size()` регистрируются в нем и блокируются
- при вызове метода `arriveAndDeregister()` происходит регистрация последнего участника, барьер "открывается", все потоки продолжают свою работу. При этом этот метод автоматически уменьшает количество зарегистрированных участников для следующего этапа, но в данном коде это не имеет значения.

---

Отвечая на конкретные вопросы:

> Вызвав метод arriveAndAwaitAdvance(), он присоединяет нить, в которой
>   вызван, к пасеру в состоянии прибыла на барьер?

Да.

> Phaser понимает, что нити являются его участниками, за счет методов
>   arriveAndAwaitAdvance и arrive?

Да.

> Без их вызова в данной задаче он будет пустой?

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду. Он будет "пустой" в том смысле, что счетчик зарегистрированных участников в нем будет равен нулю.

---

P.S. Кстати у вас есть проблема с полем `isEveryoneReady` -- доступ к нему не синхронизирован и вы можете получить несколько сообщений "Игра началась!".

Comment: Спасибо,я давно сюда не заходил. Но все вспомнилось сразу)

Comment: @PodKrepkimChaem не за что!